# Importing data into array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a school assignment that I feel should be relatively simply, but I've spent like 5 hours on this part now and can't figure out what I need to do. I'm trying to import 3 integers from each line in a file into 3 different arrays. Each line has an ID number, store number, and quantity ordered. I want to store them in 3 arrays, where the same index would address the integers taken from the same line in the text file.

Recommendations I'm getting from various other places say to use `stringstream` or a `vector`, neither of which I have used before and I assume are not needed at this point in the class. My code currently is:

```
bool loadArrays(const char* fileName, long idArray[], int storeArray[], int qtyArray[], int    &count, int maxCells)
{
    count = 0;
    ifstream fileIn;
    fileIn.open("data.txt");
    int x = 0;
    while ((fileIn.get()) && (x < maxCells))
        {
            fileIn >> idArray[x] >> storeArray[x] >> qtyArray[x];
            count++;
            x++;
            std::cout << idArray[x] << endl;
        }
    fileIn.close();
    return true;
}
```

It loops through fine. I'm passing the count variable by reference and printing it out after I run this function it gives me `20`. However the `cout << idArray[x]` line above just displays `0` each time like I'm not importing data correctly?

I'm probably importing the data wrong, which is fine for now, but even so shouldn't I get at least SOMETHING in idArray[0]? The first line of data.txt is '16724 27 134' so idArray[0] should = 16724, yes? I thought the `>>` will import integers until it meets whitespace, so the numbers being spaced apart like above means that line should go into 3 arrays per line right?

I should point out I'm taking this course online for now to see how I like programming and my teacher effectively doesn't speak english so I'm kind of on my own learning this for now.

Comment: I wonder if it's essay writing competition in C++.

Comment: What's the purpose of `fileIn.get()`? It's supposed to obtain a single character from the stream but you don't seem to be using its value.

Comment: Just trying to explain my problem bro

Comment: You increment `x` before the `cout`. Increment `x` after the `cout`.

Comment: Can you show us the contents of the file?

Comment: Do you mean the txt file or the entire c++ file? I didn't want to paste the entire c++ since its over 100 lines and thats both a pretty big block of code and the rest of it doesn't really matter for now, but the txt file is '16724 27 134
53602 83 233
75840 32 683' repeated over 20 total lines. (16724 27 134 is 1 line, 53602 83 233 is line 2, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You're reading into position x of your array, and printing out position x + 1 (x++ between those lines), which obviously is still empty.

Try to print before incrementing x, like so:

```
fileIn >> idArray[x] >> storeArray[x] >> qtyArray[x];
std::cout << idArray[x] << endl;
count++;
x++;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `fileIn.get()` without using its return value. The `get()` method extracts on character from the stream and returns it, it doesn't check whether there's still a character in the stream.

You should put the actual input operation inside the loop parameters as it is a much better way of checking if the stream performed a successful read:

```
while ((fileIn >> idArray[x] >> storeArray[x] >> qtyArray[x]) && (x < maxCells))
```

Also, as pointed out in the comments, you're incrementing `x` before printing `idArray[x]`, so it will skip the first index. Put `x++` *after* the insertion.

Comment: Indeed that was pretty silly, I've switched it to print, then increment x++ and count++ afterwards. If I change my while() loop to include the input operation like that however, then it no longer loops at all. Is <code> fileIn >> idArray[x] >> storeArray[x] >> </code> etc not the correct syntax for reading from a file then?

Comment: @user3814831 Found a little mistake: switch the `(x < maxCells)` and the `fileIn >> ...` part so `(x < maxCells)` comes first. BTW How do you know it doesn't loop?

Comment: In the original question I have a line that prints to standard cout 'idArray[x]' and so if it was looping correctly it would print out 0 20 times, but its not doing that now. When I switched the while() loop argument from the original questions fileIn.get() to the argument above, 'fileIn >> idArray[x] etc' it will no longer loop so I'm assuming that new argument is the issue there.

Comment: @user3814831 Create a character `char c;` above the loop and change the file read to `fileIn >> c >> idArray[x] >> ...`. See if that helps.

Comment: No change with the >> c >> line, it still doesn't insert anything into any of the arrays. This is how you would pull data from a txt file right? Using the ifstream object then >> then wherever you want to put the data?

Comment: @user3814831 Yes, the extractor (`operator>>()`) is used to read data from the stream into various objects. I tried to reproduce your example [here](http://rextester.com/GHUM61555) and everything works fine.